# placing image in front of another with jquery or css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two images which overlap in front of each other. I need to be able to bring forward the back image when click it.

What is the simplest way to do it, I also need to make sure that it can be used on mobile. I am using Bootstrap for making things responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `tabindex` to your elements you can use CSS's `:focus`. Add in a little javascript to trigger it on `mouseover` too for your hover.

```js
$(".image").on("mouseover", function() { $(this).focus(); });
```

```css
.image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background:red;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}
.image:focus {
    z-index:10;
}


.imageOne {
    margin-left: 60px;
    background: black;
}

.imageTwo {
    margin-left: 30px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageOne image click-to-top" tabindex="1"></div>
<div class="imageTwo image click-to-top" tabindex="2"></div>
<div class="imageThree image click-to-top" tabindex="3"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

http://jsfiddle.net/29u8S/8/

You would need to fix your css to make it work.

```
   .imageTwo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background:red;
    position: absolute;
}

.imageOne {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    background: black;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the set the position to fixed on your .image in your CSS.  Add the following and it'll be fixed:

```
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this article for more details

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

```js
$('.imageTwo').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass("opacity");

});
$('.imageOne').click(function() {
  $('.imageTwo').removeClass("opacity");

});
```

```css
.image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: red;
}
.imageOne {
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
}
.opacity {
  opacity: 0.99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imageOne image click-to-top"></div>
<div class="imageTwo image click-to-top"></div>
```